# Android table align tidy with frozen header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to create a table with a frozen header. I can achieve that by having a tablelayout which encompasses a scrollview wrapping another tablelayout but my header alignment is out.

Heres the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TableLayout>
```

and heres the code

```
public class PrepositionRulesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rules);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        createTableHeader();
        createTableBody();
      //  alignRows();
    }

    private Collection<Preposition> load(Context context) {
        DataSource<Preposition> dataSource = new DataSourceFactory().createPrepositionDataSource(context);
        return dataSource.get();
    }

    private void createTableHeader() {
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_header);
        tableLayout.addView(createHeaderRow(), 0);
    }

    private void createTableBody() {
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_body);

        int row = 0;
        TableRow tableRow = createHeaderRow();
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, row++);
        for (Preposition preposition : load(this)) {
            tableLayout.addView(createBodyRow(preposition), row++);
        }
    }

    private TableRow createHeaderRow() {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rowLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        row.setLayoutParams(rowLayout);
        row.addView(createCell(getString(R.string.preposition)));
        row.addView(createCell(Kasus.Akkusativ.name()));
        row.addView(createCell(Kasus.Dativ.name()));
        row.addView(createCell(Kasus.Genitiv.name()));
        return row;
    }

    private TableRow createBodyRow(Preposition preposition) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rowLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        row.setLayoutParams(rowLayout);
        row.addView(createCell(preposition.getPreposition()));
        row.addView(createCell(preposition.contains(Kasus.Akkusativ)));
        row.addView(createCell(preposition.contains(Kasus.Dativ)));
        row.addView(createCell(preposition.contains(Kasus.Genitiv)));
        return row;
    }

    private void alignRows() {
        TableLayout headerLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_header);
        TableRow headerRow = (TableRow)headerLayout.getChildAt(0);

        TableLayout bodyLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_body);
        TableRow bodyRow = (TableRow)bodyLayout.getChildAt(0);
        headerLayout.setLayoutParams(bodyLayout.getLayoutParams());

        for(int i = 0; i < bodyRow.getChildCount(); i++) {
            headerRow.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(bodyRow.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams());
        }
    }

    private View createCell(boolean isEnabled) {
        if (isEnabled) {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
            return view;
        }
        return new Space(this);
    }

    private View createCell(String text) {
        TextView view = new TextView(this);
        view.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 5);
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        view.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I thought I could achieve the alignment by adding a copy of the header row to the body table and than copying its layout to the row added to the header table but that did not work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**Image showing misalignment:**

[image: [Image showing misalignment]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be hard to control the alignment in a tablelayout, because a column's width will always depend and will be affected by another column's width of another row in the same table.

In order to create a table with tidy alignment, I would suggest you use a LinearLayout (for the header and row) and listview to show to items (row).

Example row.xml for both table's header and list's row:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/model"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/model"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/color"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/status"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how you apply it in your activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"/>

    <include layout="@layout/row"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly, you inflate the same row.xml for each of your list item in your listview's adapter. Below here is the screenshot of the table created by the above xmls. Kindly note that I have removed the divider and set the textstyle to normal programmatically when showing each row item in the table.

[image]